# Javascript function works in chrome and safari but breaks in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a script which fetches profile pics from an api, then calls upon a plugin that organises them into a grid.  The plugin has many animation types so I have made a function which reloads it and sets the new animation.

The plugin looks for img tags inside the li

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ultimatekingpotato-profile_image-ae8563aeda4ee1c4-300x300.jpeg"/></a></li>
```

then converts them to a style with background.

```
<a style="background-image: url('http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/mathruppenthal-profile_image-8057144b43c310c1-300x300.png'); cursor: default;" id="0" href="#"></a>
```

When I fetch the images from api I load them as img tags then the plugin converts. To reload the plugin I clone and convert the images back to normal  tags so the plugin can start all over again with the new animation.

This works fine in Chrome and Safari, but it just breaks in Firefox (**when I change animation on the select**) and I get the errors

```
GET 
http://localhost:3000/grid/%22http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/wooodus-profile_image-f70bb3ae646de522-300x300.jpeg%22
```

I am not sure where it is getting the server path from and doing this?  I have uploaded an example here so you can see it works in chrome but in FF it breaks all the images http://178.79.171.188/grid/

Here is the code for the select that causes this issue

```
$("#animselect select").change(function(){
    var Grid = $("#twitch-grid-preview").clone();
    $("#twitch-grid-preview").html("").replaceWith(Grid);
    var anchor = $("#twitch-grid-preview").children('ul').find('a');
    anchor.each(function() {

        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
        $(this).parent().append('<a href="#"><img  /></a>');
        $(this).parent().find('a img').attr( 'src' , bg );
        $(this).remove();
    });
    var animPreview = $('#animselect select').val().toLowerCase();
    var clones = $('ul#gridList li').clone();
    $('ul#gridList').append(clones);

    $('#twitch-grid-preview').gridrotator( {
        animType: animPreview,

    });
});
```

Comment: I just ran it in Firefox and it works just fine. Running Firefox v39.0.

Comment: Could the quotes %22 have something to do with it? Perhaps you just need to urlencode the image url as well

Comment: FireFox v38.0.5 on OS X. Works fine as well. When you say it breaks all images - you're referring to the initial load, correct?

Comment: No, it breaks when changing animation.  Im using FF v39 on the mac.  Here is an image showing the issue http://i.imgur.com/bNRNtmG.png

Comment: You should post your code from when the `select` changes then.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated with the specific function that listens for the select change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.css("background-image")` in firefox will return this:

```
"url("URL_PATH")"
```

whereas other browsers might return this

```
"url(URL_PATH)"
```

so your problem occurs in the first case, where you will set your image url to this:

```
<img src=""YOUR_URL"">
```

To solve this problem you can add a replace to this line:

```
bg = bg.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace(/"/g, '');
```

Comment: Amazing!  This has solved the issue.  Thankyou so much, i've been racking my brains for hours on this!